# Build production to AppStore and got warning

Tags: ios, xcode

In this January 2019, I build production to AppStore and got this warning :
"SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 11.4 SDK. Starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later."

This month is still January 2019, not yet reach March 2019.

How to fix this?

Comment: It's simple I think you have to upgrade your code to latest swift version(4.2) and also provide iPhone X series phone support (Notch display phones) and also make a build using latest Xcode(10.1) so this will be fixed and for more information, you can check this official link: - https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submissions/

Comment: @iOSTeam, wrong. it is actually can build, but that warning is weird because appear before march 2019

Comment: It's actually a warning and information that developer needs to take care and I have given reason behind that warning so you can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

This warning informs you that you're currently using the iOS 11.4 SDK, and that starting in March, you will have to use the iOS 12.1 SDK. If you want to avoid the warning, migrate to the new SDK now instead of waiting until March, when this will become a hard requirement.

Comment: last submit to AppStore this warning disappear. Maybe Apple put it after March begin.